# Visual Studio "illegal use of this type as an expression"

Tags: c, visual-studio

I've just started using Visual Studio (I got VS 2012 from dreamspark, and it hasn't been long since I've started using Windows again) and I'm having some trouble.

I have a single file named "main.c" under my Source Files folder that looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct S_s S;
struct S_s {
    void* x;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int N;
    scanf("%d", &N);

    S* s;
    printf("%p", s);

    return 0;
}
```

And when I try to build it gives me the following error messages:

```
Error   3   error C2065: 's' : undeclared identifier    c:\users\math4tots\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\algorithms\lecture1\main.c 13  1   Lecture1
Error   4   error C2065: 's' : undeclared identifier    c:\users\math4tots\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\algorithms\lecture1\main.c 14  1   Lecture1
Error   2   error C2275: 'S' : illegal use of this type as an expression    c:\users\math4tots\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\algorithms\lecture1\main.c 13  1   Lecture1
```

The funny thing is that it builds just fine if I comment out the `scanf` line.

I did create an "Empty project" under the "Visual C++" options so I wasn't sure if VS compiled it as a C or C++ program. However, I was under the impression that my code was C/C++ agnostic enough that it should compile in either C or C++.

What can I do to get this to build while still maintaining the semantics of the program?

Comment: Been ages for me... but does the typedef have to follow the struct it references?

Comment: Looks like its trying to compile it as c, not c++.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The code is legal C++ and legal C99, but not legal C89. Variable declarations in C89 must come at the beginning of a block, so having `S* s;` after `scanf("%d", &N);`
 is not OK in C89.

Comment: It's been legal C since C99. Some compilers haven't been updated to match.

Comment: I'm getting this error with MVS 2014 when running a 32 windows application......whyyyy

Comment: @BDillan: Strange. Visual Studio does have rather poor C99 support, but variable declarations anywhere in a block should be supported by Visual Studio 2013 and higher.

Answer (score 5):

Haven't tried it, but old C rules (prior to C99) only allowed declaration of auto variables at the beginning of a block. So under those rules, the intervening `scanf` makes the declaration `S* s` illegal. Commenting out the `scanf` "fixes" the problem. This has always been legal in C++.